# How to create "Select" using ASP Classic where data source from Ms SQL Server and passing primary key?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am newbie to programming. I want to build a web app using ASP Classic to pull out data from SQL Server and display it on a web page.

In my test database in SQL Server Express, I have 3 tables with the following structure:

[image]

In the `Person` table, there are columns `FirstName` and `LastName`. I have created select menu using ASP Classic using the following script I got from internet:

```html
<%
  'Set Variable
  Dim objCN 'ADO Connection Object
  Dim objRS 'ADO Recordset Object

  'Create a Connection Object
  Set objCN = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

  'Connect to SQL Server Database, connection string in Global.asa file                      
  objCN.Open Application("ConnStrTestDB")

  'SQL Query for select Person Name
  strSQLPerson="SELECT FirstName, LastName, PersonID FROM Persons ORDER BY FirstName ASC"

  'Create Recordset
  Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  objRS.Open strSQLPerson, objCN
%>

  <form method="post" action="testDBSelectProductType.asp">
    Choose Person Name <select name="FirstName">
  <%
    Do Until objRS.EOF
    Response.Write("<option")
    If objRS.Fields("FirstName")=FirstName Then
      Response.Write("selected")
    End If
    Response.Write(">")
    Response.Write(objRS.Fields("FirstName"))
    objRS.MoveNext

    Loop
    objRS.Close                
    Set objRS=Nothing
  %>                    
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Click to continue..">
  </form>

<%
  'Close the Connection             
  objCN.Close
  Set objCN = Nothing            
%>
```

Currently the Select menu only pull out the `FirstName`.

First question, how can I add the `LastName` to the Select menu? I want the select menu to be "FirstName LastName".

Second question, how can I include the `PersonID` (it is the primary key) into the form? So I can use it as query string parameter for the next ASP page.

Really appropriate any help.

Thanks

Comment: You write `<option` tag start but no end tag `</option>` and when it is selected you write `selected` without a space, so the HTML generated will be `<optionselected>` instead of `<option value="yourPersonID" selected>yourFirstName</option>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<%
Do Until objRS.EOF
Response.Write("<option value=""" & objRS.Fields("PersonID") & """")
If objRS.Fields("PersonID")=PersonID Then
  Response.Write("selected")
End If
Response.Write(">")
Response.Write(objRS.Fields("FirstName") & " " & objRS.Fields("LastName"))
objRS.MoveNext

Loop
objRS.Close                
Set objRS=Nothing
```

%>

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I like it in this way. I will insert the word "selected" into the option-tag, when the item should be selected.

```
<%
Do Until objRS.EOF

sSel="":If objRS.Fields("PersonID")=PersonID Then sSel=" selected "
Response.Write "<option value="""&objRs.Field("PersonID")&""" "&sSel&">"
Response.Write(objRS.Fields("FirstName") & " " & objRS.Fields("LastName"))
Response.Write "</option>"
objRS.MoveNext

Loop
objRS.Close                
Set objRS=Nothing
%>
```

Have fun
Michael

Answer (score -1):

Hi can you try code

```
 <select>
     <%
     get_select=objRS.Fields("id")
     Do while not objRS.EOF
     %>

 <option value="<%=objRS.Fields("id")%>" <%if get_select=objRS.Fields("id")then%> selected <%end if%>><%=objRS.Fields("FirstName")%> <%=objRS.Fields("LastName")%></option>

     <%
     objRS.MoveNext
     Loop
     %>    
    </select>
```

Comment: Hi Hasan, thanks for helping. I have tried your code, I can get the FirstName but no LastName yet. And the PersonID doesn't pass to the next page. My expectation I can get FirstName LastName show up on the Select menu. And the PersonID data can be get using Query String on the next page.

Comment: i m added Last Name in option select

Answer (score -1):

Thanks very much Michael and A. Fabiani, both your solution are working.

Here a solution from Michael:

```
<%
'Set Variable
Dim objCN 'ADO Connection Object
Dim objRS 'ADO Recordset Object

'Create a Connection Object
Set objCN = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Connect to SQL Server Database, connection string in Global.asa file                      
objCN.Open Application("ConnStrTestDB")

'SQL Query for select Person Name
strSQLPerson="SELECT FirstName, LastName, PersonID FROM Persons ORDER BY FirstName ASC"

'Create Recordset
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open strSQLPerson, objCN
%>

<form method="post" action="testDBSelectProductType2.asp">
Choose Person Name <select name="PersonID">
<%
DO Until objRS.EOF
sSel="":If objRS.Fields("PersonID")=PersonID Then sSel=" selected "
Response.Write "<option value="""&objRS.Fields("PersonID")&""" "&sSel&">"
Response.Write(objRS.Fields("FirstName") & " " & objRS.Fields("LastName"))
Response.Write "</option>"

objRS.MoveNext

Loop
objRS.Close
Set objRS=Nothing
%>                    
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Click to continue..">
</form>

<%
'Close the Connection             
objCN.Close
Set objCN = Nothing            
%>
```

And below is a solution from A Fabiani:

```
<%
'Set Variable
Dim objCN 'ADO Connection Object
Dim objRS 'ADO Recordset Object

'Create a Connection Object
Set objCN = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Connect to SQL Server Database, connection string in Global.asa file                      
objCN.Open Application("ConnStrTestDB")

'SQL Query for select Person Name
strSQLPerson="SELECT FirstName, LastName, PersonID FROM Persons ORDER BY FirstName ASC"

'Create Recordset
Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRS.Open strSQLPerson, objCN
%>

<form method="post" action="testDBSelectProductType2.asp">
Choose Person Name <select name="PersonID">
<%
Do Until objRS.EOF
Response.Write("<option value=""" & objRS.Fields("PersonID") & """")
If objRS.Fields("PersonID")=PersonID Then
Response.Write("selected")
End If
Response.Write(">")
Response.Write(objRS.Fields("FirstName") & " " & objRS.Fields("LastName"))

objRS.MoveNext

Loop
objRS.Close                
Set objRS=Nothing
%>                    
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Click to continue..">
</form>
<%
'Close the Connection             
objCN.Close
Set objCN = Nothing            
%>
```

And then I grab the PersonID on the next ASP page using Query Form, as below:

```
'Get PersonID value from Form             
PersonID = Request.Form("PersonID")
```

I hope the code above may help the others who facing the same issue like I have.